# API Communication Between 2 Containers

Tags: docker, .net-core, docker-compose, docker-network

I am using docker-compose in two separate API Projects in .NET Core 3.1

- ContainerAuth (Container running Auth API)
- ContainerAppApi (An API for a separate app)

**ContainerAuth** has an endpoint I need to hit from **ContainerAppApi**

Endpoint on **ContainerAuth**

`POST`: `http://locahost:5000/auth/validate`

I have the **ContainerAppApi** running in a separate docker container (entirely different repo/project/etc..). That is running on `http://localhost:5100`

**Issue**
When making a request from **ContainerAppApi** -> **ContainerAuth** I receive the below exception:

> Cannot assign requested address Cannot assign requested address

From what I've read, the issue is that **ContainerAppApi** doesn't know about **ContainerAuth**'s Api running on `http://localhost:5000`

I thought I could establish a bridge network, but I still get the same error. I have verified both containers are connected to my bridge network, so, *am I missing a port binding of some sort? Or is there some extra step within the networking process that I'm missing?*

**docker-compose** for **ContainerAuth**

```
version: '3.4'
services:
  web:
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:443;http://+:80
    build:
      context: ..
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 5000:80
      - 5001:443
    networks:
      - my-network
networks:
  my-network:
    driver: bridge
    external: true
```

**docker-compose** for **ContainerAppApi**

```
version: '3.4'
services:
  web:
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:443;http://+:80
    build:
      context: ..
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 5100:80
      - 5101:443
    networks:
      - my-network
networks:
  my-network:
    driver: bridge
    external: true
```

**docker network ls**

```
NETWORK ID          NAME                DRIVER              SCOPE
23179718cd0a        bridge              bridge              local
431eba987024        host                host                local
733c83d6dee2        my-network          bridge              local
2bf6118b71a4        none                null                local
```

**docker network inspect my-network**

```
[
    {
        "Name": "my-network",
        "Id": "733c83d6dee2d8ffb007bdb99324e9312a07d5735d329059a2083a11c1582642",
        "Created": "2020-07-11T02:28:09.2078715Z",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": {},
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.21.0.0/16",
                    "Gateway": "172.21.0.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": false,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {
            "741624d9304add4d39bc0dc30b04af2fc26a36e87565d87ac5eca44b2a2e361e": {
                "Name": "ContainerAppApi_web_1",
                "EndpointID": "623a99e45344ef52c8352fa1a35a6f02c8417107d85bccae6a06289c73b0d4c5",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:15:00:03",
                "IPv4Address": "172.21.0.3/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "74c08686a62f6028a74796c41f4b2fcfe9e6818588783c3ab0e76665acd032d7": {
                "Name": "ContainerAuth_web_1",
                "EndpointID": "6bb7a30f2d231514a3569481de166d46c30c78b70b725e5ee595d027dab1639f",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:15:00:02",
                "IPv4Address": "172.21.0.2/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {},
        "Labels": {}
    }
]
```

It looks like everything is connected, but what can't **ContainerAppApi** call **ContainerAuth**'s API? Both are up and running and I can hit each of the api's with Postman.

Answer (score 1):

If both docker-compose project using same network then you can call **ContainerAuth's** service by service name instead of `localhost`, localhost mean **this container** means `ContainerAppApi` container.

You will need little changes to make it working, replace the service name and use internal `PORT` that is `80` and `443`. publish port is for outer world communication.

**API**

```
version: '3.4'
services:
  api:
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:443;http://+:80
    build:
      context: ..
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
```

**Auth**

```
version: '3.4'
services:
  auth:
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:443;http://+:80
    build:
      context: ..
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
```

Now you can access **auth** from **API** container using its service name

```
curl api
```

Here is the simples example for your understand

nging service

```
version: '3.4'
services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:alpine
    networks:
      - my-network
networks:
  my-network:
    driver: bridge
    external: true
```

Alpine service

```
version: '3.4'
services:
  web:
    image: node:alpine
    command: sh -c "apk add --no-cache curl && curl nginx"
    networks:
      - my-network
networks:
  my-network:
    driver: bridge
    external: true
```

Once you up Nginx and then up Alpine you will able to see

```
curl nginx
```

This call seems working.

Comment: You just save my workweek.